# Add a minimalist WEB-Interface to a long-running process

Tags: scala, web-applications, web-frameworks

I have an application that performs long-running computations, usually on remote server. I want to add a minimal web-frontend that can perform some of the following tasks

- report progress, estimate runtime
- change some parameters (e.g. parallelization level)
- pause and resume the computation

The server will only have to handle very few connections, so there is no performance pressure.
I also want the frontend to be minimal effort, and in the best case without additional project complexity (no html, css, javascript files); just some scala code files.

Are there any options/libraries that allow me to easily add an embedded webserver that serves very simple pages?

Comment: And what do you want to use to generate html markup, some GWT/swing-like framework?

Comment: @Tyth I think that would be my preference. Though I am even willing to write some inline HTML, though I cannot estimate the effort for this very well.

Comment: very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9933211/86485